# Low-energy string effective action valid for large dilaton field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, quantum-gravity, effective-field-theory

The low-energy effective action of the bosonic string in the critical dimension $D=26$ is given by:

$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa_0^2}\int d^{26}x\sqrt{-G} \left[ \phi^2\left( R-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda} \right) + 4\partial_\mu\phi \partial^\mu \phi\right].$$

which involves the dilaton field $\phi$, the metric $G_{\mu\nu}$ and the gauge-invariant field strength $H_{\mu\nu\lambda}=\partial_\mu B_{\nu\lambda}+\partial_\nu B_{\lambda \mu}+\partial_\lambda B_{\mu\nu}$.

In section 7 of his [string theory lectures](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) David Tong says

> The caveat "low-energy" refers to the fact that we only worked with one-loop beta functions which requires large spacetime [radius of] curvature.

My question is this:

Is the above action valid for large values of the dilaton field $\phi$?

David Tong says that the action has been computed only at tree level in string perturbation theory so that $\phi \sim 1/g_s$ where $g_s$ is the string coupling.

However David Tong says that the derivation of the above effective action is valid provided the string length is much greater than the radio us of curvature of the target spacetime.

Maurizio Gasperini, Professor of Theoretical Physics, INFN and Department of Physics, University of Bari, Italy told me in an email

> a growing dilaton [field] necessarily leads to the strong coupling regime,
> where quantum loop corrections are needed.

Comment: Prof Maurizio Gasperini told me that a growing dilaton field leads to the strong coupling regime where quantum loop corrections are needed.